# How implement bootstrap into a custom meteor email?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, sendmail

How can I implement bootstrap into a custom meteor email?

I tried this, but I cant reach that bootstrap styles to display in my email
Any ideas?

```
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Accounts} from "meteor/accounts-base";

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html  = function(user, url) {
        return '<head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script><link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></head><body></body><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"><h1>Gracias por tu registro.</h1><a href="' + url + '">Verficar email</a></div></div>';
    };
}
```

Next, this is the code html inside `Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <h1>Click to confirm email.</h1>
        <a href="' + url + '">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Thanks, I hope someone helpme**

Comment: You don't really need bootstrap just for element width and margin in the first place I reckon.

Comment: You should use **inline styles** instead since email clients will generally remove head tags anyways. See [Common HTML MIstakes](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/common-html-mistakes) for additional information.